# cert-manager Found pod with acme-order-url annotation set to that of Certificate, but it is not owned by the Certificate resource

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I am working with cert-manager in my kubernetes cluster, in order to get certificates signed by let'sencrypt CA to my service application inside my cluster.

**1. Create a `cert-manager` namespace**

```
⟩ kubectl create namespace cert-manager
namespace/cert-manager created
```

**2. I've created the CRDs that helm need to implement the CA and certificates functionality.**

```
⟩ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetstack/cert-manager/release-0.7/deploy/manifests/00-crds.yaml

customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/certificates.certmanager.k8s.io created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/challenges.certmanager.k8s.io created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/clusterissuers.certmanager.k8s.io created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/issuers.certmanager.k8s.io created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/orders.certmanager.k8s.io created
[I] 
⟩
```

**3. Disable resource validation on the cert-manager namespace**

```
⟩ kubectl label namespace cert-manager certmanager.k8s.io/disable-validation=true 
namespace/cert-manager labeled
[I]
```

**4. Add the Jetstack Helm repository and update the local cache**

```
⟩ helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io 
"jetstack" has been added to your repositories
[I] 
~
⟩ 

⟩ helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Skip local chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "jetstack" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈ 
[I]
```

**5. I've installed cert-manager inside my k8s cluster using helm:**

```
     helm install \ 
    --name cert-manager \ 
    --namespace cert-manager \ 
    --version v0.7.0 \ 
    jetstack/cert-manager
```

**6. I've created an ACME Issuer including `http challenger provider`** to obtained by performing challenge validations against an ACME server such as Let’s Encrypt.

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Issuer 
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
 acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: b.garcia@possibilit.nl
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging 
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    http01: {}
```

- Apply in the same namespace (default) in where is located my service application which I want to get the certificates.

```
⟩ kubectl apply -f 01-lets-encrypt-issuer-staging.yaml  
issuer.certmanager.k8s.io/letsencrypt-staging created 

⟩ kubectl get issuer --namespace default 

NAME                  AGE 

letsencrypt-staging   22s
```

- This have the following description: We can see that `the ACME account was registered with the ACME` and the `Status` is `True` and `Ready`

```
⟩ kubectl describe issuer letsencrypt-staging --namespace default 

Name:         letsencrypt-staging 
Namespace:    default 
Labels:       <none> 
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: 

                {"apiVersion":"certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1","kind":"Issuer","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"letsencrypt-staging","namespace":"default... 

API Version:  certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1 
Kind:         Issuer 
Metadata: 
  Creation Timestamp:  2019-03-13T10:12:01Z 
  Generation:          1 
  Resource Version:    247916 
  Self Link:           /apis/certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/issuers/letsencrypt-staging 

  UID:                 7170a66e-4578-11e9-b6d4-2aeecf80bb69 

Spec: 
  Acme: 
    Email:  b.garcia@myemail.com 
    Http 01: 
    Private Key Secret Ref: 
      Name:  letsencrypt-staging 
    Server:  https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory 
Status: 
  Acme: 
    Uri:  https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/8550675 
  Conditions: 
    Last Transition Time:  2019-03-13T10:12:02Z 

    Message:               The ACME account was registered with the ACME server 

    Reason:                ACMEAccountRegistered 
    Status:                True 
    Type:                  Ready 

Events:                    <none>
```

**7. I've created the certificate in the same namespace in where the Issuer was created (default) and referencing it:**

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging
  #namespace: default 
spec:
  secretName: zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-tls 
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
  commonName: test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl

  # http01 challenge
  acme:
    config:
    - http01:
        ingressClass: nginx
        # ingress: nginx # kong-ingress-controller # nginx

      domains:
      - test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl
```

- Apply the certificate

```
⟩ kubectl apply -f 02-certificate-staging.yaml  
certificate.certmanager.k8s.io/zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging created
```

- I execute the  `kubectl describe certificate zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging` and I can see, the following:

```
⟩ kubectl describe certificate zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging 
Name:         zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1","kind":"Certificate","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging","names...
API Version:  certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2019-03-13T19:32:25Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    321283
  Self Link:           /apis/certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/certificates/zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging
  UID:                 bad7f778-45c6-11e9-b6d4-2aeecf80bb69
Spec:
  Acme:
    Config:
      Domains:
        test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl
      Http 01:
        Ingress Class:  nginx
  Common Name:          test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl
  Issuer Ref:
    Name:       letsencrypt-staging
  Secret Name:  zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-tls
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2019-03-13T19:32:25Z
    Message:               Certificate issuance in progress. Temporary certificate issued.
    Reason:                TemporaryCertificate
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>
```

We can see that the `Status` is `False` and the certificate issuance is temporary.

- This certificate, create a secret named `zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-tls` which have my private key pair `tls.crt` and `tls.key`

```
⟩ kubectl describe secrets zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-tls 

Name:         zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-tls 
Namespace:    default 
Labels:       certmanager.k8s.io/certificate-name=zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging 

Annotations:  certmanager.k8s.io/alt-names: test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl 
              certmanager.k8s.io/common-name: test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl 
              certmanager.k8s.io/ip-sans:  
              certmanager.k8s.io/issuer-kind: Issuer 
              certmanager.k8s.io/issuer-name: letsencrypt-staging 
Type:  kubernetes.io/tls
Data 
==== 
ca.crt:   0 bytes 
tls.crt:  1029 bytes 
tls.key:  1679 bytes
```

**8. Creating the ingress to my service application**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kong-ingress-zcrm365
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" 
    certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: http01
    # certmanager.k8s.io/acme-http01-ingress-class: "true" 

    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: true
    # this annotation requires additional configuration of the 
    # ingress-shim (see above). Namely, a default issuer must 
    # be specified as arguments to the ingress-shim container.
spec:
  rules: 
  - host: test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: zcrm365dev
          servicePort: 80
        path: / 
  tls: 
  - hosts: 
    - test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl
    secretName: zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-tls
```

- Apply the ingress

```
⟩ kubectl apply -f 03-zcrm365-ingress.yaml  
ingress.extensions/kong-ingress-zcrm365 created
```

- I can see our ingress

```
⟩ kubectl get ingress -n default
NAME                        HOSTS                                ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
cm-acme-http-solver-2m6gl   test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl                   80        3h3m
kong-ingress-zcrm365        test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl   52.166.60.158   80, 443   3h3m
[I]
```

The detail of my ingress is the following:

```
⟩ kubectl describe ingress cm-acme-http-solver-2m6gl
Name:             cm-acme-http-solver-2m6gl
Namespace:        default
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host                                Path  Backends
  ----                                ----  --------
  test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl  
                                      /.well-known/acme-challenge/br0Y8eEsuZ5C2fKoeNVL2y03wn1ZHOQwKQCOOkyWabE   cm-acme-http-solver-9cwhm:8089 (<none>)
Annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:                         nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range:  0.0.0.0/0
Events:                                                <none>
[I] 
~/workspace/ZCRM365/Deployments/Kubernetes/cert-manager · (Deployments)

---

⟩ kubectl describe ingress kong-ingress-zcrm365
Name:             kong-ingress-zcrm365
Namespace:        default
Address:          52.166.60.158
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-tls terminates test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl
Rules:
  Host                                Path  Backends
  ----                                ----  --------
  test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl  
                                      /   zcrm365dev:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type:            http01
  certmanager.k8s.io/issuer:                         letsencrypt-staging
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type":"http01","certmanager.k8s.io/issuer":"letsencrypt-staging"},"name":"kong-ingress-zcrm365","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"zcrm365dev","servicePort":80},"path":"/"}]}}],"tls":[{"hosts":["test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl"],"secretName":"zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-tls"}]}}

Events:  <none>
```

When I perform all this, I can see that my application service is exposed via  `kong-ingress-zcrm365` ingress, because is reached with my  test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl domain.

But as you can see, I don't get the `https` certificate to my service. The `https` is an insecure connection

- I've checked the logs of my cert-manager pod and I have the following:

```
kubectl logs pod/cert-manager-6f68b58796-hlszm -n cert-manager

I0313 19:40:39.254765       1 controller.go:206] challenges controller: syncing item 'default/zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-298918015-0'
    I0313 19:40:39.254869       1 logger.go:103] Calling Discover
    I0313 19:40:39.257720       1 pod.go:89] Found pod "default/cm-acme-http-solver-s6s2n" with acme-order-url annotation set to that of Certificate "default/zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-298918015-0"but it is not owned by the Certificate resource, so skipping it.
    I0313 19:40:39.257735       1 pod.go:64] No existing HTTP01 challenge solver pod found for Certificate "default/zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-298918015-0". One will be created.
    I0313 19:40:39.286823       1 service.go:51] No existing HTTP01 challenge solver service found for Certificate "default/zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-298918015-0". One will be created.
    I0313 19:40:39.347204       1 ingress.go:49] Looking up Ingresses for selector certmanager.k8s.io/acme-http-domain=4095675862,certmanager.k8s.io/acme-http-token=919604798
    I0313 19:40:39.347437       1 ingress.go:98] No existing HTTP01 challenge solver ingress found for Challenge "default/zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-298918015-0". One will be created.
    I0313 19:40:39.362118       1 controller.go:178] ingress-shim controller: syncing item 'default/cm-acme-http-solver-2m6gl'
    I0313 19:40:39.362257       1 sync.go:64] Not syncing ingress default/cm-acme-http-solver-2m6gl as it does not contain necessary annotations
    I0313 19:40:39.362958       1 controller.go:184] ingress-shim controller: Finished processing work item "default/cm-acme-http-solver-2m6gl"
    I0313 19:40:39.362702       1 pod.go:89] Found pod "default/cm-acme-http-solver-s6s2n" with acme-order-url annotation set to that of Certificate "default/zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-298918015-0"but it is not owned by the Certificate resource, so skipping it.
    I0313 19:40:39.363270       1 ingress.go:49] Looking up Ingresses for selector certmanager.k8s.io/acme-http-domain=4095675862,certmanager.k8s.io/acme-http-token=919604798
    I0313 19:40:46.279269       1 controller.go:206] challenges controller: syncing item 'default/zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-tls-1561329142-0'
    E0313 19:40:46.279324       1 controller.go:230] ch 'default/zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-tls-1561329142-0' in work queue no longer exists
    I0313 19:40:46.279332       1 controller.go:212] challenges controller: Finished processing work item "default/zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging-tls-1561329142-0"
    [I]
```

I think that the **http challenge process is not performed**, because let'sencrypt not trust in that I am the owner of the https://test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl/index.html domain.

How to can I solve this in order to get TLS with letsencrypt?
Is possible that do I need to use `ingress-shim` functionality in my helm cert-manager and/or `WebhookValidation` ?

---

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

I am currently using [kong-ingress-controller](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/deployment/aks.md) like ingress to my deployment.

[I've installed of this way in this gist](https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/494b006fced3ac6ee1608e5237144810#file-kongwithingress-yaml-L436).

But I am not sure of how to can I integrate my `kong-ingress-controller` to work with cert-manager when I am creating my `zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging` certificate signing request.

This is my current view of my kong resources

```
⟩ kubectl get all -n kong 
NAME                                           READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/kong-7f66b99bb5-ldp4v                      1/1     Running     0          2d16h
pod/kong-ingress-controller-667b4748d4-sptxm   1/2     Running     782        2d16h
pod/kong-migrations-h6qt2                      0/1     Completed   0          2d16h
pod/konga-85b66cffff-6k6lt                     1/1     Running     0          41h

NAME                              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
service/kong-ingress-controller   NodePort       10.0.48.131   <none>          8001:32257/TCP               2d16h
service/kong-proxy                LoadBalancer   10.0.153.8    52.166.60.158   80:31577/TCP,443:32323/TCP   2d16h

NAME                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/kong                      1         1         1            1           2d16h
deployment.apps/kong-ingress-controller   1         1         1            0           2d16h
deployment.apps/konga                     1         1         1            1           41h

NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/kong-7f66b99bb5                      1         1         1       2d16h
replicaset.apps/kong-ingress-controller-667b4748d4   1         1         0       2d16h
replicaset.apps/konga-85b66cffff                     1         1         1       41h

NAME                        COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/kong-migrations   1/1           86s        2d16h
```

The service `service/kong-proxy` provide me the external or public IP and when I create the `kong-ingress-zcrm365`, this ingress take that external IP address provided by kong-proxy. But of course in the ingress I am indicating that use nginx and not kong-ingress-controller.

And by the way I don't have installed nginx ingress controller, I am a little confuse here.

If someone can point me in the correct address, their help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
First check if using nginx ingress then nginx ingress controller is tunning
```

you are right track but have to added the ingress controller for ingress? if you are using the nginx ingress you have to add the controller in the K8s cluster.

your way and approach is perfect cert-manager and everything. here sharing the link of one tutorial check it out it is from digital ocean :

this link is same approch as you following just compare steps

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

if any issue drop comment for more

Comment: HI Harash, thanks for the answer, you has touch an important aspect, and what happens is that I am currently using [kong-ingress-controller](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/deployment/aks.md) like ingress to my deployment. [I've installed of this way in this gist](https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/494b006fced3ac6ee1608e5237144810#file-kongwithingress-yaml-L436) But I am not sure of how to can I integrate my `kong-ingress-controller` to work with cert-manager when I am creating my `zcrm365-lets-encrypt-staging` certificate signing request.

Comment: Can you see my **IMPORTANT UPDATE** section at the end of my question please?

Comment: @bgarcial yes it is coming

Comment: this is your correct address for ingress : 52.166.60.158

Comment: yes, it is my address of my ingress provided for kong-proxy such as I have in my update.

Comment: in the documentation of your load balancer they are using so try it.

Comment: can you point me to the correct docs please?  maybe this one? https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/deployment/aks.md#test-your-deployment I have the ingress of the same way (I've added the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` annotation), but now, my domain is not redirect to my service. https://test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl/

Comment: docs is perfect you are referring have to added A record in DNS ? and added ingress routing rule ?

Comment: Yes my https://test1kongletsencrypt.possibilit.nl/ is an A record in our DNS service provider, and currently my ingress with the rule  is created [of this way](https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/a0f304158d9e03ac3dd102eb0595b96f)

Comment: change A record value in DNS record to load balancer ip address...your A record for this URL(domain) record will be change to LB IP

Comment: Load balancing ip address is another kind of DNS record? It's related with this? https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/dns-load-balancing/

Comment: yes and your swagger is running on url you can check

Comment: @bgarcial now your service is running and accessible just check for certificate and cluster issuer ...you are getting certificates for stagging enviroment so that it is http...change let's encrypt url to production so https will be there

Comment: Yes, I've added again these two annotations  `certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"` (indicating my issuer) and `certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: http01` (performing an http challenge maybe ..?) And I've removed the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` annotation  and my url domains works

Comment: ok thankyou for sharing ....now just you can change tp production url and you will be done with it

Comment: Do you mean if I change my URL in the ACME server in my issuer and I use the letsencypt-production secrets tls generated I can get the https? This means that staging environment does not provide https? It's only for tests?   and What about of my DNSload balancing IP address, should to I change my DNS A record, or for the moment only change to production environment?

Comment: you are absolutely right with staging http is there for testing for production https tls secret will come and you can add to ingress. for your DNS your ip address will be same as it is no need to change anything in DNS.

Comment: ingress object in kubernetes is for routing so you can use same IP of load balancer for another domain...like example.com and add one ingress on your cluster which host is example.com and attach service...so all routing will manage by ingress external IP will be same

Comment: i think you try and skip one step of certificate ...no need to add kind:certificate just add issuer and it will creat automatically secret and use that secret to ingress for https

Comment: I understand, that same have the digital ocean guide that you sent me. I have the following doubt. What is the best approach, use a ClusterIssuer or use an Issuer, if I have many services inside my cluster, I could to have a ClusterIssuer issuing certificates to many services. Currently I have one Issuer and one service in the same namespace, If I add other service in other namespace I have to create other Issuer in that same namespace ... really?\

Comment: that is depends on you but i think same clusterissuer will not for more then one unless and untill you are getting certificate for *.example.com

Comment: in cluster issuer or in issuer you add `privateKeySecretRef` which add secret (tls) that contain `tls.crt` it will work as `certificate` for one particular domain so i think for each domain you have to manage issuer

Comment: How much time spent letsencrypt-prod to issue my certificate? I've created the issuer with the production server URL and I've added the secrets to ingress [of this way](https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/5c290be3b95199323615db3afdb73781) and [the describe of the issue is ok](https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/7b6b3a07a66f49f529d6eba8fcc0404b), my account was created in the acme server but [the describe of my certificate letsencrypt-prod is not issued](https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/ca253f5494edb10328266d8dc8920b8e) Maybe I have to create my issue like ClusterIssuer?

Comment: yes you can go for cluster issuer but for production also it's take few seconds only if let's encrypt can solve domain

Comment: I've wanted reproduce exactly the behavior that I have in this other question. Please if you can see it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184844/https-encryption-is-not-active-for-my-domain-my-order-certificates-is-not-compl I would appreciate

Comment: Yes it is perfect you can also refer the digital ocean tutorial that I had shared with you ...it’s kinda same having cert manager and ingress controller

Comment: I've referred to DO tutorial which you share with me to repeat the process and publish the post that I reference to you. The unique difference is that I am using `kong` like ingress controller insted of `nginx-ingress-controller` and I am using `jetstack/cert-manager` helm chart and in the tutorial they use `stable/cert-manager`. I have been exploring some `cert-manager` issues and I found this https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/958 but  I am not sure if maybe could to be related with my situation

Comment: i donot think much different will be there as both is cert-manager ...which will work to issue certificates only...so you have to read documentation in depth. while with helm also you can install jetstack cert-manager `helm install jetstack/cert-manager`

Comment: I've applied this `acme-kong-kube-helper` github.com/ollystephens/acme-kong-kube-helper in order to solve the `http01` validation problem in staging environment, and all it's works. When the `http01` validation to be performed, is necessary use the `letsencrypt production` environment to get the `https` encryption. The problem is mainly that cert-manager have some problems to work with other ingress controller different to nginx. This helper is a temporal solution. Currently cert-manager work in this feature to solve this https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/1097

Comment: ohh okay that is fine thankyou so much for sharing the information thanks

Comment: @bgarcial can you update status if that helps you an upvote or mark as answer. that how SO works.

Comment: Harsh actually cert-manager and kong ingress controller has this integration very well defined by using the internal certificates created when we execute the ingress resource with specific kong and cert-manager tasks, it was when I was experiencing problems some time ago. Maybe I can delete this question.